# Encode and decode the path Android

Tags: android

/storage/emulated/0/Download/ط­ظ„ ظˆط­ط¯ط© 3 ظ…ط³طھظˆظ‰ 6 ظپ2-1.pdf

I want to get the file name

Answer (score 0):

For getting file name

```
  String filename=FilenameUtils.getName("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1414240995236.jpg");
```

Hope it help

Comment: i think it's arabic alphabet

Comment: Thank you  My problem is getting a filename that is not named in English
The file name I want to get is     (/storage/emulated/0/Download/حل وحدة 3 مستوى 6 ف2-1.pdf)  When you get the path and filename (/storage/emulated/0/Download/ط­ظ„ ظˆط­ط¯ط© 3 ظ…ط³طھظˆظ‰ 6 ظپ2-1.pdf)